# On-Disk Text Processing With Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have some html files that I need to do automated processing on, basically regex replaces, but also some more complex actions like copying select blocks of text from one file to another.

I want to create a series of scripts that will let me do this processing (it will need to be done more than once on different batches of files).  It would be trivial to use Go for this (read the file into memory, regex, save to disk) but I am the only member of the project that's familiar with Go.

Javascript is a tad more ubiquitous, and I do have project members who are familiar with the language, so it's a better fit in that respect.  If I'm not around later, someone else could edit the scripts.

Is there a simple way to write some JS scripts to do on-disk text processing?  I'm looking for a cross-platform solution (OSX, Windows).  Ideally, once the scripts are written, they can be executed by double-clicking an icon--there will be "not computer people" involved at some point.

Also, I'd like to be able to do some kind of alert/message box to inform the user of the success/failure of the script.  (This may be a tall order, and is of secondary importance.)

*What I've looked at:*

- Node.js was the first thing that popped into my head, because I know that it has file system access tools, and obviously regex capacity.  But I've never used Node before, and based on the tutorials I've read, it seems like overkill for something this simple.
- There's a whole slew of "javascript compiling" tools that you can find by googling around.  Some are not cross-platform, some seem old or not actively maintained, etc.  None of them caught my eye as easy to pick up and just write some JS scripts with.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js is a simple solution and with it's framework you can create or later modify your script to your needs. This way you will not be locked down by someone else's code. And it is not that difficult to to use. 
Here is a quick tutorial on accesing files using node.js

http://www.sitepoint.com/accessing-the-file-system-in-node-js/

And here is a quick tutorial on using a node module called Cheerio. It allow you to access html files using "jquery like syntax". You don't need to use regex.

http://maxogden.com/scraping-with-node.html

I worked on a project for a client once and it required parsing thru hundreds of html files to check and replace certain image files based on certain criterias. I wasn't familiar with node at the time so I read some tutorials and wrote the script in about an hour.

And as long as Nodejs' path is set, you can run it on the command line.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much what I wanted; Cheerio looks awesome. It sounds like your old project and my current one are similar. Anything to add on giving feedback to a user who is running a node script via the gui?  (Message box or something like this?)

Answer (score 1):

Some tips:

You need any kind of DOM HTML parser, not only JS nor specifically JS.

You can do that thing with Java with use of [jTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) or [jSoup](http://jsoup.org/) libraries (I've used second one few times). It's pretty simple language to learn if you know JS and IDE like Netbeans helps a lot. So can be made quickly with that.

You can use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/page-automation.html) to create some job files and create shell/batch code to run them on some files. You might need to write a generator for job files (like taking a list of files, creating job files for each and running them).

You can use Node.js which isn't much overkill, I'm sure any solution won't be trivial.

You can create an ETL for processing with for example [Pentaho ETL](http://community.pentaho.com/) (which has JS embedded as one of two scripting languages... but without DOM parser - for that one you would need to use a bit of Java there and some library in way similar to [this article](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2011/05/using-tidy-to-clean-webpages-with.html)).

You can also do that with PHP with [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) - so you can make a service online (or on local server) that takes those html files and throws out processed ones.

Comment: Thanks, but I think you missed the part: *"I do have project members who are familiar with the language [javascript], so it's a better fit in that respect."* I *chose* JS because I have team members that know it; I'm not interested in a Java solution (yikes!), or a PHP one, or this...Pentaho thing, which looks *way* (!!!) overkill. PhantomJS looks like it would do the job, but Node seems much easier. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

First I think you underestimate the complexity. The statement

> "It would be trivial to use Go for this (read the file into memory,
>   regex, save to disk) but I am the only member of the project that's
>   familiar with Go."

is probably *false*. Parsing HTML with RegExp is just a bad idea. (Google it and you will see why)

Second, if you can trivially write the code using RegExps in Go, you can just as easily write the same thing in Javascript. They both support RegExp and file operations. If you are unsure about the Javascript/Node.js details, I suggest writing the trivial solution in Go and then translate the thing into Javascript with a colleague.

Since Javascript is a script language, writing command line utilities in Node.js is straight forward.

Some pointers to get you started

- [RegExp in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)
- [Building command line apps in Node.js](http://blog.mohammedlakkadshaw.com/command_line_apps_in_node.js.html#.VFVHN4vF8a4)

Comment: *Yea, though I walk through the valley of the shadow of regex, I will fear no Cthulhu.* :) Don't worry, I'm tracking; I am not attempting to *parse* html with regex per se; more like find-and-replace. But the Cheerio module mentioned by jsdev will help. Thanks for your input.